# I'm trying to wake on lan, but I get ethtool: command not found error

Tags: linux, command-line, wake-on-lan

It's driving me crazy... I've been googling for an hour now and nothing!

I'm trying to invoke this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ethtool -s eth0 wol g
exit
```

I run it as **root**: /etc/init.d/wakeonlanconfig

And it gives: **/etc/init.d/wakeonlanconfig: line 2: ethtool: command not found**

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell environment's path variable doesn't have the directory where ethtool is located. So either add it to your path, or better, just prefix "ethtool" with its full path: /foo/bar/ethtool